# How to dynamically enable/disable <preference> in di.xml?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, di

I currently have the following `<preference/>` in one of my di.xml file:

```
<preference for="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="RadTest\TestModule\Controller\Contact\Post" />
```

I have an enable/disable configuration option for my module in the admin panel. I only want the `<preference>` to be enabled when my custom configuration option is set to enabled.

How can I dynamically enable and disable the `<preference/>` overriding according to the configuration of my module is set?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you cannot enable and/or disable preferences based on a config setting.
`di.xml` is just configuration. you cannot have logic in it, but you can do something else.
You can have in your class a condition that checks your config flag and does some action accordingly.
I assume your class `RadTest\TestModule\Controller\Contact\Post` extends `Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post` because you have to override at least one method.
let's say you have to override the method `execute`.
You can make your class do this:

```
namespace RadTest\TestModule\Controller\Contact;
class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
{
    ....
    public function execute()
    {
        if (your config setting is disabled) {
            return parent::execute();
        }
        //your custom logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I've been doing and was thinking it will be nice if there is a way to dynamically disable them. Now I know we can't. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Can I use this in `Vendor/Module/Plugin/Customer/Account/CreatePost.php` too?

Comment: @Butterfly. Sure. You can use it anywhere you want.